# How to get the difference of different row

Tags: sql

I have the following table:

```
name        date      price
productA    Jan2019   3000
productA    Feb2019   3500
productA    Mar2019   3200
productB    Jan2019   2500
productB    Feb2019   2700
productB    Mar2019   2800
```

I want to calculate the % change of Mar2019 and Feb2019 of each product. For example, for productA, the percentage is (3200-3500)/3500=-8.6%

The desired result is

```
name         date        %change
productA     Mar2019     -8.6
productB     Mar2019     3.7
```

How to write the sql command?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation.  Something like this:

```
select name,
       (1 - 
        max(case when date = 'Mar2019' then price end) / 
        max(case when date = 'Feb2019' then price end) 
       )
from t
group by name
```

Comment: One downfall would be that this would have to be actively managed. You'd have to constantly update case statements. My solution would avoid this.

Comment: @PPJN . . . The question is specifically about March 2019 and Feb 2019.  If the OP has a more general requirement, then that should be asked as another question.

Answer (score 0):

To make the process much more clean, I would recommend storing your date as a date and making it the first of the month. This way it would be an easier join. You would join on the product and the date less 1 month for the prior month. Where there isn't a prior month, I input `NA`.

```
create table #test  (
                        name    varchar(16)
                        ,[date] date
                        ,price  decimal(18,2)
                    )

insert into #test
values      ('productA',    '2019-01-01',   3000),
            ('productA',    '2019-02-01',   3500),
            ('productA',    '2019-03-01',   3200),
            ('productB',    '2019-01-01',   2500),
            ('productB',    '2019-02-01',   2700),
            ('productB',    '2019-03-01',   2800)


select      a.name                      name
            ,format(a.date,'yyyyMM')    [date]
            ,case
                when b.date is not null then cast(cast((a.price - b.price)/b.price * 100 as decimal(18,1)) as varchar(25)) + '%'
                else 'NA'
            end                         change
from        #test   a
left join   #test   b   on      b.name = a.name
                            and b.[date] = dateadd(month,-1,a.date)


drop table #test
```